Is the gcc compiler that is responsible for storing ( in the executable ) utf8 characters from a C language char array?
I'm on an Ubuntu system and I wrote this simple program :
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main( void ){

    char utf8_arr[] = "写一个名字列表: \n\n";
    
    write(1,utf8_arr,sizeof(utf8_arr));
    
    
    char utf8_buff[1024];
    ssize_t r;
    
    while ( (r = read(0,utf8_buff,sizeof(utf8_buff))) > 0 ){
    
             
             write(1,utf8_buff,r); 
             
    }
    
     return 0;

}

My questions :
1)Who controls the character encoding ( the way actual characters are stored in memory ) when it comes to C language strings like the one in my program ? Is it the gcc compiler ( that in turn gets its own character encoding settings from somewhere ) ?
2)Is it 100% correct to use utf8 char string just for storing ,writing and reading the way my program does ?
3)What about sizeof ? Is it fine to use it like this ?


1)Who controls the character encoding ( the way actual characters are
stored in memory ) when it comes to C language strings like the one in
my program ? Is it the gcc compiler ( that in turn gets its own
character encoding settings from somewhere ) ?

Th C language spec says that there are two relevant "character sets", by which it means a set of abstract characters combined with an encoding for the set's members.  There is a source character set and an execution character set, where members of the latter are represented in source code by members of the former or by escape sequences.  This distinction is mostly about the encoding side, not the identities of the abstract characters that are covered.
C specifies a collection of characters that must be members of these sets, and must be represented in each via single code units the size of char (which can vary in principle, but in practice is almost always 8 bits).  C allows other characters at the discretion of the C implementation, and allows that some of these may have multi-byte representations.
The way characters are represented in C source code is the source character set.  They way they are presented to the execution environment at runtime is the execution character set.  I'm not sure that C actually specifies either one as an in-memory representation, but the execution character set is the only pragmatic choice for that.
Who controls? Which character sets are used / supported is at the discretion of the C implementation, such as GCC + Glibc or GCC + musl or MSVC + MSCRT.  There is no specification for who actually controls, but it is the implementation that determines who controls.  In GCC-based systems, GCC defines the defaults, and these can be overridden via command-line options, within limits based on the system's iconv library.  Ultimately, then, the user controls.

2)Is it 100% correct to use utf8 char string just for storing ,writing
and reading the way my program does ?

No. C does not require any particular source character set to be used or accepted, and it does not define what execution character set must be used.  There is no guarantee that all C implementations will interpret your source the way you intend, or even that GCC specifically will interpret it the way you intend under all circumstances.
Supposing that you can rely on C11 or later, you can address the in-memory representation by using UTF-8 literals, which have elements of type char and are expressed in source code with a u8 prefix:
    char utf8_arr[] = u8"写一个名字列表: \n\n";

You are still subject there to source character set considerations, but you can rely on UTF-8 for the in-memory representation.

3)What about sizeof ? Is it fine to use it like this ?

It depends on what you expect it to do, but the example uses look ok to me.  In particular, you can rely on sizeof utf8_arr to correctly yield the number of bytes occupied by utf8_arr, whatever the relevant execution character set requires that to be for the initializer provided.

so how can I determine what is the encoding used by my C implementation ? I mean, it looks like it is utf8 but where can I see it ?

@Kode1000, That's what documentation is for. For GCC, the details are covered in several places, but this seems to be the main one: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html.  Note that those docs mischaracterize some of the provisions of the language spec, but that's mostly harmless in this case.
